# knn imputer combine with grid search

Tags: python, knn, grid-search

I'm trying to impute missing values from my data frames and for this, I use knn imputer. I want to combine the knn imputer and grid search but I don't know how to do that . i try this code

```
alphas_knn_imputer =list(range(10,40,1))
params_knn_imputer={'KNNImputer__n_neighbors':alphas_knn_imputer}
knn_imputer =GridSearchCV(KNNImputer(),params_knn_imputer,cv=4)

num_proc_knn = make_pipeline(
    knn_imputer,
    StandardScaler()
)

processor_col_inknn = make_column_transformer(
    (num_proc_knn, num_cols),
    remainder='passthrough')
    
   
lineare_reg_knn = make_pipeline(processor_col_inknn,LinearRegression())
lineare_reg_knn.fit(X_train,Y_train)
lineare_reg_knn.score(X_test,Y_test)
```

I have this error:

```
If no scoring is specified, the estimator passed should have a 'score' method. The estimator KNNImputer(add_indicator=False, copy=True, metric='nan_euclidean',
           missing_values=nan, n_neighbors=5, weights='uniform') does not.
```